# Background Music plays when app is closed

Tags: android, playback, android-broadcast

I manage to add background music to my apps, but when i close it, it doesn't stop. When I click on `HOME`, or `BACK` button, it still plays music. Does anyone knows how to solve that problem?

```
MediaPlayer bsound;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    MediaPlayer bsound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
    bsound.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    bsound.setVolume(100,100);
    bsound.start();

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Schalk.ttf");  
    txt.setTypeface(font); 

    TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Schalk.ttf");  
    txt1.setTypeface(font1);            
}

public void list(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menus.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pause and resume MediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer bsound;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    bsound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
    bsound.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    bsound.setVolume(100, 100);
    bsound.start();

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Schalk.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);

    TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Schalk.ttf");
    txt1.setTypeface(font1);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (bsound.isPlaying()) {
        bsound.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    bsound.start();
}
```

And yes, you didn't initialize that `MediaPlayer bsound` field. Change this line:

```
MediaPlayer bsound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
```

to this:

```
bsound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
```

Comment: @user3153271 Please accept his answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of his answer. It's a good answer and it obviously helped you.

Comment: another problem sir. when i change activity it stop i want background music that continues playing when app is use the if i press home button it will stop sorry for my english am not good in english :)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `onStop()` for your activity and stop your music playing in this method. This will stop it whenever your activity closes. Look here for a bit more info

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Comment: I already dot that this is my code for  onStop

public void onStop()
 {
    super.onPause();
    if (bsound != null && bsound.isPlaying()) {
      bsound.stop();
      bsound.release();
      bsound = null;
  
 }}
but it doesnt work

Comment: Check if onStop() is called. And do that action in on Pause.
And yes, you haven't initialize that MediaPlayer bsound field.

Comment: I'm absolutely beginner sorry for bothering you guys but can you please tell me what to do

Comment: I've added an answer, try it.

Comment: sorry yakiv your answer is nice but there is one problem if i change activity the background music stop what should i do with that sorry for not checking your answer early i really dont know that i need to do that hahaha please help me

Comment: You should use Service for that bg music. Here you can find a lot of information about it. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

Call pause() method in onPause() in activity and start in onStart() method.

Comment: I'm absolutely beginner sorry for bothering you guys but can you please tell me what to do

Comment: That first answer above should do the trick. Its complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Copy below code and paste AndroidManifest.xml file in under First Activity Tag.

```
<activity                        
            android:name="com.FirstActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">              

        </activity>
```

Also Add this below code in all under Activity Tag in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```